# Appending numpy arrays by column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays of shape:

```
x.shape # (50000, 784)
y.shape # (50000,)
```

Why can't I use:

```
X_y = np.hstack([X, y])
```

My desired outcome is to add y as another column to X

```
X_y.shape # (50000, 785)
```

Comment: `X_y = np.column_stack([X, y])`

Comment: `y` needs to be 2d like `x`, e.g. (50000,1) shape.  `np.concatenate((x, y[:,None]), axis=-1)`.

Comment: @coldspeed I get MemoryError with this